# How to avoid ScheduledToastNotification from launching the App on UWP?

Tags: notifications, uwp, xamarin.forms

I have a kind of alarm on my App.

It's working fine, but when it finishes all I want is to pop-up the notification. I have a button to dismiss and another one to snooze. Both of them open the app once tapped. I don't want this behavior. All I need is to snooze it or dismiss it and that's it.

Is it possible?

Here is how I'm doing it:

```
    var xmlString = @"<toast launch='args' scenario='alarm'>
        <visual>
            <binding template='ToastGeneric'>
                <text>" + alertAction + @"</text>
                <text>" + alertBody + @"</text>
            </binding>
        </visual>
        <actions>

            <action arguments = 'snooze'
                    content = 'Snooze' />

            <action arguments = 'dismiss'
                    content = 'Dismiss' />

        </actions>
    </toast>";
    var doc = new Windows.Data.Xml.Dom.XmlDocument();
    doc.LoadXml(xmlString);
    var toast = new ScheduledToastNotification(doc, DateTimeOffset.Now.AddMinutes(durationInMinutes), new TimeSpan(0, 0, 300), 5);        
    toast.Id = id;
    ToastNotificationManager.CreateToastNotifier().AddToSchedule(toast);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current action will generate a ToastButton type, which is normal `activationType` & will active the app when tapped. If you don't want to active the app, declare `activationType` to `system`.

Try to use

```
 <actions hint-systemCommands = 'SnoozeAndDismiss' />
```

or add `activationType="system"` in each of action

```
<actions>

        <action activationType="system"
                arguments = 'snooze'
                content = 'Snooze' />

        <action activationType="system"
                arguments = 'dismiss'
                content = 'Dismiss' />

</actions>
```

Comment: That did the trick. Thanks. May I ask you where I can find those xml customization options? I just can't find it.

Comment: @Dpedrinha [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/controls-and-patterns/tiles-and-notifications-adaptive-interactive-toasts)

Comment: You can also find it in [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tiles_and_toasts/2015/07/02/adaptive-and-interactive-toast-notifications-for-windows-10), same as above

Comment: @TeaNguyen's link was moved before it was archived, but I believe it pointed to [this](https://web.archive.org/web/20160206082722/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tiles_and_toasts/archive/2015/07/02/adaptive-and-interactive-toast-notifications-for-windows-10.aspx).